# How to override variable value for GN target/template?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, build-tools, gn

I've added `shared_library` GN target in my Chromium build. It has an extension according to defined in `toolchain.gni`rules:

```
# Extension for shared library files (including leading dot).
if (is_mac || is_ios) {
  shlib_extension = ".dylib"
} else if (is_android && is_component_build) {
  # By appending .cr, we prevent name collisions with libraries already
  # loaded by the Android zygote.
  shlib_extension = ".cr.so"
} else if (is_posix) {
  shlib_extension = ".so"
} else if (is_win) {
  shlib_extension = ".dll"
} else {
  assert(false, "Platform not supported")
}

# Prefix for shared library files.
if (is_posix) {
  shlib_prefix = "lib"
} else {
  shlib_prefix = ""
}
```

I want to change an extension so i need to override `shlib_extension` variable but only for my `shared_library` target. If i modify `toolchain.gni` it will affects all targets that use `shlib_extension` variable.

I'd like not to use `output_name` shared_library attribute as i can see using `out_name="lib${target_name}.cr"` makes the following `v8.ninja`:

```
...
output_extension = .so
output_dir = .
solibs = ./libv8_libbase.cr.so
```

but if having `shlib_ext=".cr.so"` makes the following `v8.ninja`:

```
...
output_extension = .cr.so
output_dir = .
solibs = ./libicui18n.cr.so ./libicuuc.cr.so ./libv8_libbase.cr.so
```

(it means `output_name` changes file **name**, not **extension**)

As logical continuation of the question is it possible to override variables like `is_debug` or `is_component_build` not in .gn file but for target/template only?

Let's say i want to build `V8` just like `is_component_build=true` (and do it in `v8.gni` in templaets) but the rest code taking default or user-defined variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case adding [`output_extension`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs/reference.md#output_extension) worked for me:

```
shared_library(target_name) {
  output_extension = "cr.so"
  ...
}
```

Not sure about general case of overriding variables.